# How do I get the value of a Form into an SQL query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to get an Access SQL query that does this (semi-pseudocode below)

```
UPDATE SignIn SET SignIn.Complete=True, CompletedBy=(Select [FirstName] & " " & [LastName] AS EmployeeName From UserList where POid = Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtPOid), CompletedDateTime=Now()
```

So after the query would run, the data in the database would look like

```
Complete EmployeeName CompletedDateTime
True     John Smith   3/23/2017 8:34:10 AM
```

THe update query doesn't work because of syntax and not sure how to fix it.

The exact error message is

> Invalid Memo, OLE, or HyperLink Object in subquery '[FirstName] & " "
>   & [LastName]'.

Comment: It would update all records in SignIn. Probably not what you want.

Comment: it is what i wanted

Comment: Oh, I missed your exact error. See edit please.

Comment: I would use `DLookup()` instead of a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The query could be throwing a fit because of the Double Exclamation marks. Instead of

`Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtPOid`

Try

`Forms!HiddenUserCheck.txtPOid`

You also have an extra `)` at the end of your WHERE Statment

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it but it complains about [FirstName] & " " & [LastName]. Specifically says "Invalid Memo, OLE or Hyperlink Object in subquery [FirstName] & " " & [LastName]

Answer (score 0):

OK, then your issue may be that the subquery may return more than one record:

```
UPDATE 
    SignIn 
SET 
    SignIn.Complete=True, 
    CompletedBy = 
        (Select First([FirstName] & " " & [LastName]) AS EmployeeName 
        From UserList 
        Where POid = Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtPOid), 
    CompletedDateTime = Now()
```

If your name fields are Memo/LongText fields, that may be the source of the error. If so, try:

```
UPDATE 
    SignIn 
SET 
    SignIn.Complete=True, 
    CompletedBy = 
        (Select First(Left([FirstName], 255) & " " & Left([LastName], 255)) AS EmployeeName 
        From UserList 
        Where POid = Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtPOid), 
    CompletedDateTime = Now()
```

Edit.

You may try using *DLookup* for the subquery:

```
UPDATE 
    SignIn 
SET 
    SignIn.Complete=True, 
    CompletedBy = 
        DLookup("[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]", "UserList", "POid = " & Forms!HiddenUserCheck!txtPOid & ""), 
    CompletedDateTime = Now()
```

Comment: All the fields are Short Text, Yes/No, or Date/Time fields in the SignIn table
In the UserList, the FirstName and LastName are "Long Text"

Comment: I used the query you created. I get a message saying "Operation must use an updateable query" I added a line at the end of your query to test it with 1 row. The line added was WHERE SignInID=9231;